# Excel VBA loop until

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am using the following `if` code to filter `col A` and `col B` by the value in `F1`

Once sorted I copy the the filtered values in `col A` and paste them under the range value.

Then I move on to the next range and repeat the filter using a different range value (in this case cell G1).

I need to repeat this from cell F1 through to cell AH1.

Can I use a loop to do this?

```
If Range("F1").Value <> "" Then

    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$B" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Range("F1").Value

    Columns("A:A").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("F2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("A1").Select

End If

If Range("G1").Value <> "" Then

    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$B" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Range("G1").Value

    Columns("A:A").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("G2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("A1").Select

End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the loop below. I have refactored your code to not use `ActiveSheet` and `Select` statements. Instead I qualify all objects and methods to their parent object and work directly with the object. It will avoid many pitfalls and errors in expected versus actual results of the code.

```
Dim LastRow As Long
'assume LastRow already set

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change as needed

With ws

    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In .Range("F1:AH1")
        If Len(cel) > 0 Then
            ws.UsedRange.AutoFilter
            .Range("A2:B" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=cel.Value
            .Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=cel.Offset(1)
        End If
    Next

End With
```

See [How to Avoid Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)